# C++20 co_await sleep?

Tags: c++-coroutine

With C++20 coroutines, as a toy example, I thought it would be easy to make a coroutine that returns a `task<T>` that `co_await`s a sleep before `co_return`ing. It looks like Folly can do it?: https://blog.the-pans.com/build-folly-coro/ but maybe cppcoro doesn't?

I realize C++20 coroutines are a raw compiler feature with no standard libraries yet. Does cppcoro support an awaitable sleep? If not, are there other libraries (or is there a one-pager) that I can play with on Compiler Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will return an awaitable object:

```cpp
template <typename DurationT>
auto sleep(const DurationT& d) {

    struct awaitable : std::suspend_always {
        DurationT duration_;

        awaitable(const DurationT& duration)
        : duration_(duration) {}

        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<>) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration_);
        }
    };

    return awaitable {d};
}
```

Or overload an `await_transform` from your promise type.

Sample: https://godbolt.org/z/hKP7oezv7